# handle NullPointerException java

Tags: java, python, nullpointerexception

I have a java class that checks each item of a list and does some process on it using a library ! it throws NullPointerException if it dont be able to process the item.

I am calling this class in python.

Is there any way that we be able to say do nothing if such a exception occurs?????

for example it does not recognize an item like "jeren". I could handle it for empty items but need to handle it for unknown items too.

any idea???

part of my Java class that I use it in python is:

```
public static String doStaff(String word) throws IOException {  


    String str = null;
    TurkishMorphParser parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
    str = new Stm(parser).parse(word);
    //System.out.println("str = " + str);
    String replace = str.replace("[","");
    String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
    List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
    String result = result1.get(0).toString();
    //System.out.println("Result = " + result);
    return result;


}
```

Comment: Why don't use a simple `if(someVariable != null)` check? NPE's should never get caught by a try-catch since you can easily avoid them

Comment: +1, @JeroenVannevel, I agree to you! a simple value check on an if else would be enough. :)

Comment: I did this for null items .. but as I told I need to check items that results this exception. I am doing some processes on turkish language so the function wont work properly on some words thats why it throws exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of  course you can catch NullPointerException and do nothing, but this generally is a **very bad idea** (exceptions are slow and unreadable):

```
String result;
try {
    String str = null;
    TurkishMorphParser parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
    str = new Stm(parser).parse(word);
    //System.out.println("str = " + str);
    String replace = str.replace("[","");
    String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
    List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
    result = result1.get(0).toString();
    //System.out.println("Result = " + result);

 } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
   // do nothing
}
    return result;
```

**SOLUTION.**
Instead try to make sure there are no reasons for NullPointerExceptions, e.g.

```
String result = result1.get(0).toString();
```

Here you can get NullPointerException, because you get the first element of a list which might be null. Instead you could:

```
List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
String result;
if(result1.size()>0) {
   result = result1.get(0).toString();
}
```

Comment: @Niemand I'm afraid this is nicht the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Niemand Not really. You have two cases, either a reference is allowed to be null, in which case you have to check using `if(... != null) { /* do stuff */ }` or it may not be null which indicates something went wrong in the processing before or the data is malformed, in which case you have to raise an Exception where you indicate what exactly is not correct and probably what to do to fix it. What this answer suggests is just swallowing an Exception.

Comment: If result1 would be null, then result1.size() will throw NullPointerException too...

Comment: @kamil09875 somehow I can't imagine any possibility that new ArrayList<String> could return null value. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Niemand "because you get the first element of a **list** which might be **null**"

Comment: This answer was correct .. I check the null condition in python and just needed to handle this exception in java. try catch helped me solve this :) as I said I need to check items that results this exception. I am doing some processes on turkish language so the function wont work properly on some words thats why it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException, as the name states is an Exception (run-time Exception I should say) which is thrown by the Compiler, when you try to use a Null value where a value is needed/must needed. So, the place where you're using `str` must be checked for its value, before executing some function which would require some of the checking and some valid value parameters. String can be null, but sometimes the method would need a valid value to work on.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

If you just want to **catch** the exception then here

```
try {
  String str = null;
  TurkishMorphParser parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
  str = new Stm(parser).parse(word);
  //System.out.println("str = " + str);
  String replace = str.replace("[","");
  String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
  List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
  String result = result1.get(0).toString();
  //System.out.println("Result = " + result);
  return result;
} catch (NullPointerException error) {
  /* Display message */
  System.out.print("Sorry, there was an error: " + e.Message);
}
```

However, I guess when it gives you nothing, that is the place where you might get the Error.

```
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

Maybe that is why you commented it out.

So, you can handle it too. If after all the processing of the above line, `str` is a `null`

```
if(str == null) {
  System.out.print("Sorry, doesn't recognise it.");
} else {
  System.out.println("str = " + );
}
```

Then again, move forward to the execution and check for the value again. This way, it would minimize the error! :)

Comment: NullPointerException is thrown manually or by JVM, not by the compiler